# CSS inheritance issue in a form

Tags: html, css, forms

I have 3 CSS classes here:

```
.mail-collector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.mail-collector input {
  border: solid 3px white;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255, 116, 97, 0);
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 14;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 6px 28px;
  }

.send {
  border: solid 3px red;
}
```

When I apply them on my form, I don't succeed to give the last one to the submit element (send). How can I proceed ?

```
<div class="mail-collector">
<%= form_for Subscriber.create, html: {class: "mail-collector"} do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "email address" %>
        <%= f.submit "send", class: "send" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: try using `!important` in .send class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) in you `.send` class use it like this :

```
.send {
 border: solid 3px red !important;
}
```